# Skip/filter table row

Tags: java, arrays, filter, row, processing

I am calculating the average of a table column. 
But before I calculate this, I want to filter out each row that has a certain value, 'Gender = 0'.

I've calculated the expected average in excel with gender filtered, and I fail to re-create this value in my script. I am very novice in programming and I am sure I'm doing some obvious mistake. I've tried looking at similar questions here, but can't apply them for my script.

Using processing (Java based).

**Snippet of my data**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f47bU.png]

```
//LOOP THROUGH TABLE AND FILTER
  for (int column=0; column<highTable.getColumnCount(); column++)
  {
    float ColumnTotal=0; 

    for (int row=0; row<highTable.getRowCount(); row++)
    {

//I want to filter out all rows from the table that is 'Gender = 0'
      if (highTable.getInt(row, "Gender") == 0)
      {
        continue; //I've also tried row++ here, this works depending on the value of the last row, oterhwise it crashes. Also, I think it fails to skip when there are multiple 'gender 0' in succession, bacause I've calulated the return value in excel, and this script returns a slightly wrong number. 
      }

      float rowvalue = highTable.getInt(row, column); 
      ColumnTotal += rowvalue; 
      highAverage[column]= ColumnTotal/highTable.getRowCount(); 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Don't use the "Code Snippet" tag. That is not for Java. Just select your code and use the `{}` button.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of a disconnected snippet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't calculate `highAverage[column]` until you're done with the `row` loop.
2. In doing that calculation, use the number of rows where `gender != 0`, and not `highTable.getRowCount()`.

You'll need a new local variable - same scope as your `ColumnTotal` variable.  Increment it at the same time you add `rowValue` to `ColumnTotal`.  Finally, just guard against a divide-by-zero before you calculate the average.